# Как вырезать из изображения нужные мне два прямоугольника

Tags: c#, изображения, нейронные-сети

Постановка задачи:
Есть шаблон: [image: Шаблон(скрин из фотошопа, чтобы по напрвляющим было видно о чем идет речь)]

На вход подается скрин следующего вида[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее нужно найти на входном скрине розовый прямоугольник и поместить его в розовую облась шаблона. С синей частью все тоже самое, но еще нужно захватить дату, на примере - "07 октября суббота".

Самое непонятное из этого это как определить нужное мне на входном изображении, а уже как вырезать нужный кусок и вставить его в шаблон разберусь.

Уважаемые форумчане, скажите 
1)для этого нужна нейронная сеть?
2)Реально ли написать такую нейронную сеть, которая бы возвращала на последнем шаре координаты нужных мне прямоугольников.

Буду рад Вашим подсказкам.

Answer (score 1):

тут проще не "скрин" на вход подавать а "парсить" напрямую с сайта по URL. а далее выводить в прямоугольники нужную информацию.. и далее сохранять в виде "картинки" результат, если очень надо именно картинку на выходе, в этих случаях  Нейронные сети, пункты 1 и 2, не нужны ;-)

Answer (score -1):

По-моему задача довольно простая. Классификатор Вам нужен будет только на последних этапах. Для решения я предлагаю воспользоваться [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

При решении данной задачи я делаю предположение, что все сайты (скрины) имеют одинаковую цветовую гамму.

Для начала бинаризуем изображение по порогу (его можно подобрать на cross validation, если это требуется, либо задать руками). Наша картинка будет представляться как бинарная матрица:

[image: Пример изображения]

Такая матрица эквивалентна графу, вершины которого -- есть единицы. Будем считать, что две вершины связны, если соответствующие им клетки соприкасаются по одной из сторон. В таком случае, мы можем построить выделить компоненты связности, каждая из которых будет соответствовать возможным зонам интереса.

Необходимо подобрать порог так, чтобы розовая зона оказалась связной областью, т.е. кодировалась в нашем представлении 1.

Запустим из каждого пикселя [DFS](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/connected_components). Есть реализация в [openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a). Тем самым, мы можем получить координаты окон, в которых находятся выделенные кластера. Теперь каждый кластер можно попробовать классифицировать на предмет наличия там текста (на Ваших картинках, в синем и розовом окне есть текст). Сделать это можно по-разному:

- при помощи [teseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr). Приблуда эта довольно медленная, но в качестве baseline подойдёт
- можно попробовать построить гистограмму и пробовать сравнить с некоторым эталоном
- другим вариантом будет семплировать каждый кластер и классифицировать каждый семпл, а потом смотреть на среднее количество семплов, которые были отнесены к нужному кластеру. Этот метод явно сложнее, чем предыдущие два, но, вероятно, он даст больше профита
- можно пробовать сложные архитектуры вроде u-net, но они, вероятно, здесь ни к чему, посколько задача простая: информация хорошо структурирована и объединена в группы